# Have WinInet share sessions/cookies with Internet Explorer

Tags: delphi, cookies, wininet

What I want is the following:

1)
Login at a page using Internet Explorer

2)
Have my software which uses WinInet API to crawl a site reuse the same cookies/session (i.e. so the crawler is "logged in")

I have tried build login myself using INDY, and while session cookie logins works well, many websites use a more complicated login mechanism nowadays combining client and server side stuff for the initial login.

...

The reason I believe that e.g. WordPress , ASP.Net etc. uses client-side/AJAX stuff as well with hash/time/useragent codes/checks and similar, is that I can be sending the exact same HTTP headers 30 seconds later from my own crawler program as e.g. FireFox used during a login, but it won't work.

(Compare this to normal logins based on session cookies where my own crawler program will login fine.)

Comment: Internet Explorer uses WinInet internally, so it already shares everything with other WinInet-based apps.

Comment: I hoped so as well. But if you login using IE at WordPress following by using WinInet, it does not appear to be logged in any longer. If what you say is true, I suspect the reason may be user agent changes or similar is detected by WordPress?

Comment: Quite possibly because what you are doing could also be done by malware to take control of the account or whatever it is you are accessing.

Comment: Apparently WinInet handles cookies on a per process base: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443567/how-does-wininet-handle-cookies?rq=1

Comment: I guess that essentially kills the idea of asking the user to login with Internet Explorer first. I am still open for suggestions though.

Comment: wild guess: Have you tried to read cookies via InternetGetCookie/Ex

Comment: kobik: But would that help WordPress recognize is as the same logged-in session? (Even if I myself read the cookies from and on the client, that is not the same as e.g. WordPress reads the cookie on the client as belonging to the same session?)

Comment: I never tested it. If you could get your hands on the `ASP.NET_SessionId` via InternetGetCookie/Ex you might be able to set it in your WinInet request via InternetSetCookie/Ex. (for HttpOnly cookie use INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY flag). Try it... :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems IE does not share "internet cookies" by default. In **Tools** > **Internet options** > **Security**, there are different zones. **Internet** zone is *protected mode enabled* by default and you cannot access this cookies using the Wininet API. However, the **Local intranet** zone is *not protected mode enabled* by default, so you access this cookies using the Wininet API.

The protected mode cookies are stored in **%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low** and not protected mode cookies are stored in **%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies**.

To fix your software, uncheck the **Enable protected mode** from the **Internet** zone, restart IE and log in at your website to acquire the cookies again.

Comment: I am going to try this later today

Comment: This did not appear to work with a WordPress website I tested. I will return if I find/get more information